# django-import-export outside admin

Tags: python, django, django-import-export

I am trying to implement a simple xls file import and save to a model using django-import-export.
Unfortunately the docs only cover the admin integration.
I am stuck here in my example code:

```
class UploadFileForm(forms.Form):
    file = forms.FileField()


class ExportSpec(resources.ModelResource):
    class Meta:
        model = Specialty

view:
def ca_import(request):
    if request.method == 'POST' and 'import_test' in request.POST:
        form = UploadFileForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            filehandle = request.FILES['file']
            dataset = ???
            result = ExportSpec().import_data(dataset, dry_run=False,
                                          raise_errors=True,
                                          user=request.user)
```

Can someone with understanding of this module help me complete the code for this generic example?

Or is there a generic example snipped somewhere on the net which I did not find using google?

**EDIT:**

Based on Alex answer I was able to find a working solution:

```
def ca_import(request):
    if request.method == 'POST' and 'import_test' in request.POST:
        form = UploadFileForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            file = form.cleaned_data['file']
            data = bytes()
            for chunk in file.chunks():
                data += chunk
            dataset = XLS().create_dataset(data)
            result = ExportSpec().import_data(dataset, dry_run=False, raise_errors=True, user=request.user)
```

Comment: Code looks ok so far. What kind of error are you getting, or what specific problem are you facing?

Comment: Please see the line "dataset = ???". I believe I have to get a dataset from the filehandle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use the `Format.create_dataset()` method:

```
from import_export.formats.base_formats import XLS

def your_view():
    filehandle = form.cleaned_data['file']
    data = bytes()
        for chunk in import_file.chunks():
            data += chunk
    dataset = XLS().create_dataset(data)
    result = ExportSpec().import_data(...)
```

Comment: I tried it out and I get an error with 'filehandle.content'  'ExcelInMemoryUploadedFile' object has no attribute 'content'

Comment: Sorry, I just don't have `django-import-export` installed, so it may take some time to hit the target ). What if you try the `file` field of the form? Check out the updated answer.

Comment: Your answer directed me into the right direction. I looked into the source code of the module and produced the lines of code in my edit above. Maybe there is a simpler way but this works.

Comment: Fantastic, I've updated the answer so it contains the tested code. Thanks.